# PHP singleton class with explicit pass by reference breaks singleton

Tags: php, singleton, pass-by-reference

We had to make some modifications to our internal caching class to fix issues with PHP7. In the process, we found some odd code. In the example below (pulled from the actual code), you can see two lines where the new Cache instance is instantiated. The active line in the example makes the cache act like a singleton, no problem.

The commented out line below it is what we replaced, which returns a different instance every time it is called. It almost seems like having the ampersand when the new class is already being returned as a reference *negates* the reference. I would just like to understand why.

I should mention that the "=&" method errors on PHP7, which is why we needed to fix it. Just interested on what PHP5.6 is doing with it.

```
<?php

class Cache {
    public $prefix;

    public static function &getInstance($prefix = '') {
        static $instance;

        if (!$instance) {
            $instance = new Cache($prefix);
            // $instance =& new Cache($prefix);
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    public function __construct($prefix = '') {
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
    }
}

// Example Runs

// When using just "=", one instance, acts like a singleton
$cache = Cache::getInstance('1000');
$cache2 = Cache::getInstance('2000');
echo $cache->prefix . " | " . $cache2->prefix; // "1000|1000"

// When using "=&", multiple instances, no longer acts like a singleton
$cache = Cache::getInstance('1000');
$cache2 = Cache::getInstance('2000');
echo $cache->prefix . " | " . $cache2->prefix; // "1000|2000"
```

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all with `=&`. According to the manual: `The result of the new statement can no longer be assigned to a variable by reference`, http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

Comment: @jeroen Sorry, should have mentioned that. It **doesn't** work on 7, only 5.6. We've gone ahead and removed the singleton altogether, but I'm just wondering what the heck it's doing on 5.6.